# How do I transfer values as variables using xmlhttprequest?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, xmlhttprequest

First off I am not a programmer and am relatively inexperienced with this... I am trying to use a star rating system on my site, I downloaded the scripts from [this](http://www.search-this.com/2007/06/04/css-the-star-matrix-pre-loaded-part-2/) link. I am getting them to appear on my site correctly when I preview it in my browser but when you click on a star to rate them it's not recording that rating in my database. Using firebug I think I've tracked it down to the javascript function that is transfering the data onclick through an ajax request. When I click a star, the response I get in firebug is "You shouldn't be attempting to access this file in this manner." If I comment out the if/die statement the response I get in firebug is undefined indexes, and it lists 'item', 'rating', 'classes'. The original ajax request code that the script I downloaded had is in the bottom code example. Everywhere I've read on how to do an ajax request mentioned using xmlhttprequest, so I was hoping by switching to that that would eliminate this problem, which it hasn't. I haven't gotten any syntax errors with how I have it now so I think I have the xml request formatted properly. What do you all think? Thank you in advance.

```
function RateItem(varItemId, varRate)
{
var varOrigClassName = document.getElementById(varItemId).className;
var request;
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  request=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  request=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
request.open("POST","ajax.rate.item.php",true);
//request.onload= ReloadRating;
request.setRequestHeader('item','varItemId');
request.setRequestHeader('rating','varRate');
request.setRequestHeader('classes','varOrigClassName');
request.send('item','rating','classes');
}
```

ajax.rate.item.php file

```
<?php
  require_once("classes/include.all.php");

  // Check that the data was sent
  if (sizeof($_POST) == 0
    || $_POST['item'] == null
    || strlen(trim($_POST['item'])) == 0
    || $_POST['rating'] == null
    || strlen(trim($_POST['rating'])) == 0
    || is_numeric($_POST['rating'])
    || $_POST['classes'] == null
    || strlen(trim($_POST['classes'])) == 0)
 {
    die("You shouldn't be attempting to access this file in this manner.");
  }

  echo Rating::RateItem($_POST['item'],$_POST['rating'],$_POST['classes']);

?>
```

Original ajax request

```
function RateItem(varItemId, varRating)
{
  var varOrigClassName = document.getElementById(varItemId).className;

  // Retrieve Ajax Feeds
  new Ajax.Request('ajax.rate.item.php',
    {
      method: 'post',
      parameters: {item: varItemId, rating: varRating, classes: varOrigClassName},
      onSuccess: ReloadRating,
      onFailure: RatingError
    }
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To send params with a POST method, you can try this way :

```
xmlhttp.open("POST","ajax.rate.item.php",true);
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
xmlhttp.send("item=" + varItemI + "&rating=" + varRate + "&classes=" + varOrigClassName);
```

[Source MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest#send%28%29)